# Python's concurrent.futures hangs in both multithreading and multiprocessing on some systems

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

The code I wrote is to do some data analysis work, and it has been working well for several months now. But the size of my source data increased significantly recently, and I see that the code hangs now without errors at around the same point in execution (but not always at the same point).

The code looks like this:

```py
def submission_loop(data, submission):
    # No loops in this function
    # Do some data analysis

    return result

def data_loop(arg1, arg2, data_row):
    # Check this marker against all the criteria
    results = []
    for data in data_row:
        for submission in submissions:
            results.append(submission_loop(data, submission))
            
    # Do something with result here
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count()) as executor:
        chunksize = max(1, int(len(data_rows)/cpu_count()))
        results = executor.map(functools.partial(data_loop, *args), data_rows, chunksize=chunksize)
        results = list(results)
```

Note the three levels of loops.

Now, I've tested this on 3 machines:

1. Inside a docker container running `python:3.8.5` running on an Ubuntu 20 host.
2. Inside a docker container running `python:3.8.5` running on a Windows 10 host using Docker Desktop.
3. Directly on another Windows 10 machine running `python 3.8.5`.

On both 1 and 2, the above mentioned issue is seen consistently. On 3, the task completes successfully.

I changed this to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` and the issue does not resolve, which makes me say that the number of cores is irrelevant here. If I remove `concurrent.futures` usage and use a serial loop, it works perfectly.

Is this a bug with `concurrent.futures`?

Comment: This may be caused by running out of RAM. Does your 3rd machine have more RAM than the others?

Comment: Can you modify your code so that it becomes a reproducible example? Also, passing the total number of CPUs as the max_workers limit is not a good idea. Better to pass no parameters at all for greatest efficiency and portability

Comment: As found [here](https://github.com/yeraydiazdiaz/futureproof), these are the bugs are limitations of concurrent futures. I solved the problem by using another package, Pebble, to do the multiprocessing bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my previous comment. I noticed that `pebble` also was causing similar issues. I switched to `futureproof` and the issue has been resolved.